# Is there a JAR containing only the Annotations from JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to use the JPA annotations but I don't need any JPA implementation. Where can I get the from? I didn't find anything at Oracle's Java pages ...

Comment: I am not familiar with JPA, but what are its annotations going to do without the accompanying code?

Comment: @thatidiotguy JPA is just an API. It is built around annotations you use on your POJO classes. Hibernate is an implementation of JPA.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah I see. Thank you for enlightening me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following maven artifact contains the `javax.persistence` types.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You can get the binaries [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api). Don't be fooled by the hibernate name, it does not contain any implementation.